# Collecting files (and more) in Python

Tags: python

I have three folders (say, folder1, folder2, and folder3) that contain some dbf format files. Suppose that I have:

```
0345.dbf, 2345.dbf, 4444.dbf, 6767.dbf, 7623.dbf in folder1
0222.dbf, 0345.dbf in folder2
3423.dbf, 4827.dbf, 5635.dbf, 7623.dbf in folder3
```

So, for example, "0345.dbf"s are shown folder1 and folder2. Similarly, there are two "7623.dbf"s in folder1 and folder3. But they are all different files with different contents.

I have an additional information stored in a csv file (list.csv) with two columns as follows:

```
0222 f2
0345 f2
2345 f1
3423 f3
4444 f1
4827 f3
5635 f3
6767 f1
7623 f3
```

According to that rule, I have to pick "0345.dbf" from the folder2, not from the folder1. And "7623.dbf" from the folder3, not from the folder1.

How can I collect all the nine files and save them to a folder(say, "d:/collect") following the selection rule written in the csv file? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Read the CSV file into a dict, mapping column1 to column2.   As you read the input folders, extrace the basename without the extension of each of the files (from `os.listdir` for example - snip the extension off with `rsplit` or `rpartition`).   If the lookup in the dict matches the current directory name, take this one.   Otherwise, not.